# Installing Xamarin for VS 2015 not working

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I recently installed VS 2015 Enterprise. Im trying to add Xamarin for VS from the setup menu, and when downloading it just hangs at this point for hours and eventually says an error was encountered. This is my 5th installation attempt. I dont have any other VS version installed on my machine. [image: moves no further]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1bdb79d-cce1-4058-a03d-d7431dce5498/unable-to-install-xamarin-vs2015-update-2?forum=vssetup):

1. Download Bonjour Print Services for Windows v2.0.2 and install from the following link: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_US
2. Then activate bonjour service in win10. Refer to:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7420758?start=0&tstart=0
3. Then you can re-install VS to see if it works.

By the way, that's an [open bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40062).

Comment: Im running Windows 8.1 by the way, my error log had nothing to do with Bonjour Services

Comment: Sorry Luis, added Bonjour Services, and the download worked. The logs show a lot of missing registry keys though(cant find it now)

Comment: Glad to know it worked! In case there's another problem, just let us know. Happy Coding! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install it by downloading the kit from xamarin.com? What do you mean by "from the setup menu"?

Comment: i mean the initial menu where you select components for installation, forgive the poor wording. Yeah my download is from xamarin.com

Comment: Also if Luis answer don't work either and you don't need any feature from the enterprise edition you can go for the community one. I did recently an install and it went flawless.